# Getting an AngularJS directive to function properly

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have an HTML form described as below:

```
<div>

    <div class="modal-header">
        <h3 class="modal-title">File Attachment</h3>
    </div>

    <div class="modal-body">
        <input type="file" id="inpFile" file-model="myFile" />
    </div>

    <div class="modal-footer">
        <div class="btn-toolbar pull-right" role="toolbar">
            <div class="btn-group" role="group" >
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" file-upload>Upload</button>
            </div>
            <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="$close()">Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>

</div>
```

I have my angular directive (as written on the Upload statemtn in my HTML

```
.directive('fileUpload', ['$http', function ($http)
                {
                    return {
                        restrict: 'A',
                        link: function (scope, element, attrs)
                        {
                            // Create the formdata and get the file
                            var file = document.getElementById("inpFile").files[0];
                            var formdata = new FormData();
                            formdata.append('uploadedFile', file);

                            ajaxUrl = root + 'FileUpload/upload';
                            $http.post(ajaxUrl, formdata, {
                                headers: { "Content-Type": undefined }
                            })
                            .success(function (status)
                            {
                                if (status.Succeed)
                                {
                                    alert('File Uploaded');
                                }
                                else
                                {
                                    alert(status.ErrorResult);
                                }
                            });
                        }
                    };
                }])
```

Here is the screen shot of the attachment screen in the upper right:
[image]

The issue I'm having is this:
When I click on that attachment button, the HTML form does not come up in order for me to browse, select a file and click the upload button (where the directive is).

Instead, when clicking on the attachment button, it goes directly into the directive. It does go into my MVC controller afterwards, but no files is there to validate against since the form does not come up.

Can someone please tell me what I'm doing wrong here so the form will be able to come up first to select the file, click the upload button, then have my directive submit the file to the MVC Controller...

### EDIT

Code for Attchment button which occurs on several pages:

```
<h3 class="panel-title">Check Deposit Header Information <attachment /> </h3>
```

The form is the fist screen shot of the HTML form.

I'm thinking that when you click on the Attachment button, the HTML form should come up. The when you click on the Upload button, it should hit the directive.

When you click on the "Attachment" link, the HTML code is in a directory called:
AccountingModule/modal/attachment/attachment-modal.html

Comment: Where is the code for your 'attachment button' and 'form'?

Comment: I have solved the issue by associating a click event in the directive to the Upload where the directive name is in the html.